# Get the autogenerated UUID in Cassandra from INSERT statement

Tags: cassandra

Use case:

I have a RESTful API that inserts data into Cassandra and returns ID of new entry to the user. I'm making use of `uuid()` ID generator in Cassandra for populating the ID.

Problem:

INSERT statement does not return the generated ID, yet the RESTful API I described seems like a common use case. What's a way to obtain the UUID of that exact entry? I could in theory do something along the lines of `SELECT id FROM table WHERE partition_key = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;` but that seems like it would introduce a racing condition in case two writes happen around the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do, just generate UUID yourself, and insert it. Just use library for your language. If you're using Java driver for Cassandra, you can use functions from [UUIDs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html) class: `random` - to generate random UUID (type 4), or `timeBased` for UUID for current time (type 1).

Comment: Thanks, ended up going this route. I'm actually using node.js backend with cassandra-driver, for those who run into this in the future, I found the Uuid generator in `types.Uuid.random()` part of the module.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't state that you use Spring Data, but I'm fairly certain if you used Spring Data and called the .save() when inserting it'll return the saved entity including it's auto-generated id.

See this example as a reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-crud-repository-save